# Strange google links question

Tags: search, error, google

I'm getting tons of bogus links to my EE site (ee6) when I search on Google, as in, I can see this link in google:

"https://www.andy-kirkpatrick.com/blog/view/the-haunted-cliff"

which is correct, but also this one (and many others), like this:

"https://www.andy-kirkpatrick.com/articles/view/the-haunted-cliff"

which goes to a 404 page.

There is no way that post should appear in that view template, and it does not appear in my sitemap either. I'm also getting results for

template paths for templates that I have never created on the site.

Any ideas?

Best

Andy

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that very occasionally but never found an reason as to why it happens.

Possible causes:

1. Was the URL /articles previously use before?
2. Are any external sites linking to URL's that contain /articles?
3. Have you got any (or had you ever had) internal links that point to /articles that may be crawled by search engines?
4. Does it only happen on Google or are other engines that same?